# Wordpress website with simple programs in it?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, wordpress

I am curious if I can make a Wordpress site and there are some tasks listed which use my algorithms to solve tasks depending on user input. And if I can do it, which options do I have to make this (if possible, without php)?

e.g.
I would like to have my Wordpress design including a program like this:

[image: Example]

*picture URL is showing this site:
http://www.ee.calpoly.edu/media/uploads/resources/KarnaughExplorer_1.html*

Comment: Surprise surprise - it is possible. There are at least 10 ways how you can achieve this.

Comment: If this is all you are seeking to do then you don't even need Wordpress, just some simple HTML + CSS + Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend searching for a WordPress plugin that allows you to place JavaScript on a page OR lets you insert an iFrame that could call the page you reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can accomplish what you ask.

1. You would have to create custom [theme for wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
2. You then have to create your program with standard HTML5 + CSS + Javascript
3. And then - include program in wordpress with the iframe [iframe plugin for wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/changelog/)